# merge arrays but with a same value for each

Tags: php

I would like to know what is the best way to merge some arrays with a same value.

My output :

```
array (size=16)
  'totalAttemps' => int 4
  'totalSuccess' => int 4
  'totalFailed' => int 0
  'ituCount' => int 0
  'pddSuc' => int 11543
  'pddFailed' => int 0
  'ituCount34' => int 0
  'FAS10' => int 4
  'FAS20' => int 4
  'FAS40' => int 4
  'FAS60' => int 4
  'region' => string 'TEST'
  'oneOne' => int 24
  'sixSix' => int 48
  'thirtySix' => int 120
  'sixtySixty' => int 240
array (size=16)
  'totalAttemps' => int 1
  'totalSuccess' => int 1
  'totalFailed' => int 0
  'ituCount' => int 0
  'pddSuc' => int 5829
  'pddFailed' => int 0
  'ituCount34' => int 0
  'FAS10' => int 1
  'FAS20' => int 1
  'FAS40' => int 1
  'FAS60' => int 1
  'region' => string 'TEST'
  'oneOne' => int 6
  'sixSix' => int 12
  'thirtySix' => int 30
  'sixtySixty' => int 60
```

I would like :

```
array (size=16)
  'totalAttemps' => int 5
  'totalSuccess' => int 5
  'totalFailed' => int 0
  'ituCount' => int 0
  'pddSuc' => int 17372
  'pddFailed' => int 0
  'ituCount34' => int 0
  'FAS10' => int 5
  'FAS20' => int 5
  'FAS40' => int 5
  'FAS60' => int 5
  'region' => string 'TEST'
  'oneOne' => int 30
  'sixSix' => int 60
  'thirtySix' => int 150
  'sixtySixty' => int 300
```

I can use += to count but I would count only for the same region because there are a lot of regions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more manual version than Carlos's, but very straightforward:

```
$arr1 = YOUR_ARRAY_1;
$arr2 = YOUR_ARRAY_2;
$merged = $arr1;

foreach($arr2 as $key => $val) {
    if(array_key_exists($key, $merged)) {
        $merged[$key] += $val;
    } else {
        $merged[$key] = $val;
    }
}
```

This starts with `$arr1`, and goes through each element of `$arr2`. If the key exists in `$arr1`, then add `$arr2`'s value. If not, then create a new element of the array.